# saving nodejs data on clinetside javascript var

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to save an array of objects sent from the server side in a client side var 
 but for some reason the var is a just a long string of

> "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"

insted of the actual array.

my code is as follows

```
html.no-js(lang='en')
  //<![end if]
  head
    script(type='text/javascript')
        var x = '#{Countries}';
```

Comment: Are the elements in Countries objects perchance? I guess you want to use proper JSON encoding instead of `Countries.toString()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode them as JSON.

JavaScript:

```
JSON.stringify(Countries);
```

CoffeeScript: (I think)

```
JSON.stringify Countries
```

If you would like to convert this back into an objects, you use JSON.parse, as follows

```
JSON.parse(CountriesText);
```

(encoding in JSON would have to occur on the server-side node.js instance)

Comment: Instead of `JSON.parse(X)` on the client side, just use `var x = JsonData;` in the script code.

Comment: Right, but that's only for JSON literals, from what it looks like they need to use actual strings.

Comment: Tried this an im geting an error SyntaxError: Unexpected token & from JSON.parse

Comment: Try to call .trim() on the string before you parse it